# Lenovo Thinkpad e480 wifi not working

Tags: 16.04, networking, 18.04, lenovo

I've recently purchased a lenovo thinkpad e480 and have attempted to access the internet through the wifi manager. However, in 18.04, there is no option for WiFI networks and when I try to access the wifi settings it says there is no wifi adapter. I've also run `iwconfig`, with emp3s0 and lo returning as 'no wireless extensions'. The problem persists when I try to run the laptop on 16.04. When I run `sudo lshw -C Network`, it does return an Ethernet interface and I can view a few pcis through `sudo lshw`. I've tried running through the wifi troubleshooting on the ubuntu website and cannot find the pci models in their supported chipsets. Could this mean the chipset isn't supported? If so, am I forced to buy a physical wifi adapter?

Thanks in advance

**edit:** Results of rfkill list all

```
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: No
Hard blocked: No
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: No
Hard blocked: No
```

Results of sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL811/8168/8411 PRI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
```

Running `lspci` returns several pci bridges and the ethernet controller from the previous command.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks for the welcome! I tried running the `lspci` command but there was no output. I did edit in the `rfkill` command though.

Comment: Is wireless disabled in the BIOS? http://download.lenovo.com/km/media/images/HT071417/8f357c67e94e41eabfafc9a2430f0a11.jpg

Comment: @chili555 I checked it and it said that the ethernet interface was enabled.

Comment: And how about the *wireless*; perhaps called by Lenovo WLAN?

Comment: Wireless LAN (I assume translates into wlan) is enabled in the i/o port access.

Comment: We see no evidence of an included wireless adapter. I suggest that you question the seller or buy an external device.

Comment: So I was afk for a few minutes to take a shower and the wifi miraculously started working. Basically, wifi works perfect, although it has a low range. Now when I run `iwconfig`,  there are three results. The first two don't have wireless extensions, but the last one enumerates all the data. I'm not sure what exactly I did to fix the problem, but I know I used a wired connection to perform `sudo apt-get update`. That may have fixed the problem, but I'm not sure why it's working fine now

Comment: Wow! We are glad it's working by whatever means. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

The Lenovo e480 comes with an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 wifi adapter as far as I know.
This should be supported in kernels 4.2+ but perhaps you need to do a little research into how to get it up and running.

Here is the link to Intel's page for downloading the required firmware with some instructions:

[Intel Linux Support](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)