# Yoga 910 Wifi adapter not found ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

I know there were similar question, I followed, but none of them worked for me. My laptop is lenovo Yoga 910-13.

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
 *-network DISABLED        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 32
   serial: 64:6e:69:fe:38:4b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-43-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:131 memory:a1000000-a11fffff
```

This is the output of `rfkill list all`

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I tried this `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"`, but it didn't work.

After I followed some commands like this `git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git` found in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070593/lenovo-thinkpad-e480-no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-ubuntu-18-04).

The output of `rfkill list all` was changed to

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

It made me clueless. 
Any comment would be appreciated. Thank you.

Update:

The output of `dmesg | grep ath`

```
[    2.965858] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.269973] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.269980] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.271102] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 17aa:0827
[    3.271104] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    3.271525] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 fd869beb
[    3.336839] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 20d869c3
[    3.926920] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[    3.929994] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[    3.930533] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: htt-ver 3.47 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    4.015776] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[    4.015777] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    4.015778] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    4.015779] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[    4.019754] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have included the output `dmesg | grep ath`. Thank you.