# Issues installing Wifi drivers for a Lenovo ThinkPad E480 (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: wireless, lenovo, thinkpad, ubuntu-drivers

I opted to install all third party drivers during installation, and have used a wired connection to update software, and check for additional drivers. Still no luck.

I then looked on here and found a similar thread that seemed to have helped one user but it failed to resolve my issue.

The posted solution was as follows:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git
cd rtl8821ce
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

This worked fine for me, I will post the results below:

```
gino@DrHappy:~$ sudo apt update Hit:1 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease Hit:2 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease Hit:3 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB] Fetched 88.7 kB in 2s (39.6 kB/s)                     Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done 3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list
--upgradable' to see them. gino@DrHappy:~$ sudo apt install build-essential git dkms Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1). build-essential set to manually installed. dkms is already the newest version (2.3-3ubuntu9.2). dkms set to manually installed. Suggested packages:   git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn The following NEW packages will be installed:   git git-man liberror-perl 0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded. Need to get 4733 kB of archives. After this operation, 33.9 MB of additional disk space will be used. Get:1 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17025-1 [22.8 kB] Get:2 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 git-man all 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4 [803 kB] Get:3 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4 [3907 kB] Selecting previously unselected package liberror-perl. (Reading database ... 127259 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack .../liberror-perl_0.17025-1_all.deb ... Unpacking liberror-perl (0.17025-1) ... Selecting previously unselected package git-man. Preparing to unpack .../git-man_1%3a2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4_all.deb ... Unpacking git-man (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4) ... Selecting previously unselected package git. Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb ... Unpacking git (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4) ... Setting up git-man (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4) ... Setting up liberror-perl (0.17025-1) ... Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ... Setting up git (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4) ... gino@DrHappy:~$ git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git Cloning into 'rtl8821ce'... remote: Enumerating objects: 21, done. remote: Counting objects: 100% (21/21), done. remote: Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done. remote: Total 672 (delta 7), reused 6 (delta 1), pack-reused 651 Receiving objects: 100% (672/672), 3.33 MiB | 916.00 KiB/s, done. Resolving deltas: 100% (236/236), done. gino@DrHappy:~$ cd rtl8821ce gino@DrHappy:~/rtl8821ce$ sudo ./dkms-install.sh About to run dkms install steps...

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108/source ->
                 /usr/src/rtl8821ce-v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module: cleaning build area... 'make' -j4 KVER=4.18.0-15-generic............ Signing module:
 - /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108/4.18.0-15-generic/x86_64/module/8821ce.ko Nothing to do. cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

8821ce: Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed. Finished running dkms install steps.
```

however the original user said to follow this up with

```
sudo modprobe 8821ce
```

I cannot get this command to run, and assume at this point this is why I still have no Wifi driver. When I try to run it I get the following results.

```
gino@DrHappy:~$ sudo modprobe 8821ce
[sudo] password for gino: 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8821ce': Operation not permitted
```

I tried a couple times to make sure I am not simply mistyping my password, no luck. Below here I will post a link to the original question. I tried to add this comment there but I am not allowed due to reputation limits needed for posting on that particular thread.

[Lenovo Thinkpad E480 - No Wifi Adaptor Found in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070593/lenovo-thinkpad-e480-no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-ubuntu-18-04)

If anyone could let me know where I am going wrong, or of another approach to getting my Wifi working that would be great.

Comment: Please disable Secure Boot in the BIOS/EFI and try again.

Comment: Not only did this work, I didn't even need to run the command again. As soon as I booted up after disabling Secure Boot Wifi was active.

Comment: This is a not uncommon problem. I will write an answer that the searchers can find and also that we can use as a duplicate. If my answer is helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly feel that this is the issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1806472

> "The r8822be module alias is intact, trying to modprobe it or insert
>   results in a "operation not permitted" error. "

I believe the bug is applicable to several other Realtek modules.

Please try disabling Secure Boot.

Answer (score 0):

For Updates

sudo apt install git

git clone https://github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce.git

cd rtl8821ce

sudo apt install gcc

sudo apt install make

sudo make all

sudo make install

sudo modprobe -a 8821ce

sudo -i

echo "options rtl8821ce msi=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8821ce.conf

Comment: Please do not copy and paste the same answer to multiple questions. It's kinda spammy. If there are multiple questions with the same appropriate answer, then you should try and mark one of them a duplicate of the other. You should also look at improving your formatting in the answers.