# No WiFi Adapter Found Ubuntu 18.04.02 Desktop in HP Laptop Model 15-daxxx

Tags: wireless, 18.04, laptop, hp, realtek-wireless

I've been unsuccessfully trying all the hints and suggestions found in internet for making my Ubuntu 18.04.02 Desktop in my HP Laptop Model 15-daxxx seeing the WIFI connection.

I've already done all the steps listed here [NoWiFiAdapterFoundUbuntu18.04HPLaptop](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/no-wifi-adapter-found-hp-laptops-ubuntu-18-04/#comment-3666311)
but still Ubuntu 18.04.02 Desktop says "No WiFi Adapter Found"

I've also put in HP site: [HP-drivers-laptops](https://support.hp.com/in-en/drivers/laptops) the ID number of my laptop, it was correctly identified, and the only Operating System I can choose from is Windows. Clicking on the link "I do not see my Operating System" I found in this HP webpage: [HPProducts-MyOperatingSystem](https://support.hp.com/in-en/product/hp-15-da0000-laptop-pc/20395828/model/24269506/document/c03785459/?sku=4XW78EA), I selected Linux -> [LinuxKernelArchive](https://www.kernel.org/), I downloaded the latest stable kernel and then I installed, following the instructions, the WiFi kernel iwd-0.9.
But again.... after rebooting : "No Wifi Adapter Found".

How can I solve this strange problem?
Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

Updates:
1)

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.  
RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless 
Network Adapter [103c:831a]
    Kernel modules: wl
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba America Info 
Systems Device [1179:0113] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:0001]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

2)
Following the instructions here: [networking-WiFiNotWorkingInLenovoThinkPadE570(RealTekRTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce)

I updated the Makefile in this way:

```
#export TopDIR ?= $(srctree)/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8821ce
export TopDIR ?= $ ~/Downloads/rtl8821ce
```

saved the change, and then run make:

```
  CC [M]  /home/riccardo/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/osdep_service.o
  CC [M]  /home/riccardo/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
/home/riccardo/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1325:22: error:   
initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-
pointer-types]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/riccardo/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1325:22: note: 
(near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:325: recipe for target '/home/riccardo/Downloads
/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/riccardo/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o]
Error 1
Makefile:1534: recipe for target '_module_/home/riccardo/Downloads
/rtl8821ce' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/riccardo/Downloads/rtl8821ce] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic'
Makefile:1903: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04.02 Desktop erasing all the previous content of the
  hard-disk, in order to have a cleaner situation.
  But again . after modifying the Makefile file:

```
#export TopDIR ?= $(srctree)/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8821ce
export TopDIR ?= $ ~/Downloads/rtl8821ce
```

the same error messages:

```
~/Downloads/rtl8821ce$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic/build   
M=/home/riccardo/Downloads/rtl8821ce  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic'
 CC [M]  /home/riccardo/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
/home/riccardo/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1325:22: error:
  initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-
pointer-types]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/riccardo/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1325:22: note: 
 (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:325: recipe for target '/home/riccardo/Downloads 
/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/riccardo/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] 
   Error 1
Makefile:1534: recipe for target '_module_/home/riccardo/Downloads
/rtl8821ce' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/riccardo/Downloads/rtl8821ce] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic'
Makefile:1903: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

SOLVED: thanks to the indications here: [Lenovo Thinkpad E480 - No Wifi Adaptor Found in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070593/lenovo-thinkpad-e480-no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-ubuntu-18-04), and thanks to the person who inserted this helpful link.

Comment: You tried everything, but didn't try to find out what is your wireless adapter. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I updated my question with these info. Thank you for helping

Comment: @Pilot6 I updated my question again with an error occured while following the instructions https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce

Comment: It looks like the driver is incompatible with the kernel. Please wait till someone who knows better about this driver appears @chili555

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. I keep looking and trying.

Comment: You need the tomaspinho git driver.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the wifi adapter hasn't been disabled by the keyboard hotkey or physical button/switch on the device.

If it's on it should be flashing between white and amber to show activity.

The key to enable the wifi adapter on the keyboard is on the top row and it looks like this:
((I))

Comment: The keyboard hotkey will do precisely *nothing* if there is not yet a working driver.