# No Wifi Adaptor on HP 255 G7

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop.
How do I resolve this?
Thanks

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] [1002:15dd] (rev c5)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Vega [Radeon Vega 8 Mobile] [103c:84ae]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04) && https://askubuntu.com/q/990378/480481

Comment: @pomsky I think this is more likely to compile correctly: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070593/lenovo-thinkpad-e480-no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-ubuntu-18-04/1070645#1070645

Comment: Hi again all. Thanks for the links. None of them appear to work for me. I may be doing something wrong, Also my Terminal asks me if I want to continue during the processes. I type "Y" and it responds with "abort" and stops there. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi again all. I reinstalled from scratch and now have managed to install the driver following your links. Thank you again.

Comment: I don't believe this. Had it all sorted, worked well and now it has totally disappeared. There's not even a wifi icon on the display. Can anyone advise (again) ?