# WIFI does not work on Lenovo Ideapad 120s (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, lenovo, hardware

I took apart the computer to upgrade some hardware, but afterwards I cannot connect to wifi.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

CPU: Intel Celeron N3350

[image]

[image]

Output of nmcli device show

```
> GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
> 
> GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
> 
> GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
> 
> GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
> 
> GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
> 
> GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
> 
> GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
> 
> IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
> 
> IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
> 
> IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
> 
> IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

output of lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

> ```
> 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
>
> Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
> ```

Comment: what is the output of `nmcli device show` from the terminal?

Comment: Edited in post.

Comment: seems to be drivers problem.. from the output sys didt find wifi adapter..

Comment: did it inserted properly? do you have live USB.. try with it to confirm drivers problem or hardware..

Comment: i think you may not have plugged every ribbon back in correctly :https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-remove-a-ribbon-cable-connector

Comment: It appears that the screw that holds down the wireless card and which appears to also provide an electrical ground (notice the copper trace) is missing. Did you have a screw left over after you upgraded the hardware? Please find and replace the screw and then check: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I edited it in.

Comment: What about the screw?

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, the driver must be compiled from source code: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070593/lenovo-thinkpad-e480-no-wifi-adaptor-found-in-ubuntu-18-04/1070645#1070645